# Intake Q google dictation

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Intake Q, an electronic health record, has the ability to use dictation via google API.  The issue is that it will not pick up punctuation, it wont allow me to type punctation wile activated, if there is text in the box already, it will only start typing new dictated text at the bottom of current content.

Intake Q support states this is a google API issue and I should reach out to them. What can I do?

Comment: "What can I do?" Probably nothing.